# Bug in nav bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, debugging

Something's going wrong with my menu and I can't figure out why. When I test my code in responsive view it works fine at first when it switches from the hamburger icon to the horizontal nav bar, BUT... if I click the hamburger icon **first** ( once to drop down the menu and a second time to close it) and *then* resize the screen, my horizontal nav menu disappears.

Here's the code linked in Codepen. Just go to Full View and try those steps and see what you think! Thank you!!

http://codepen.io/sshine2/pen/VbjGaE

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html lang="en">

 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");</script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

 <style>
body {
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: #ffffff;
 background-color: black;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }

header {
 width: 100%;
 background: #ffffff;
 position: fixed;
 height: 4em;
 line-height: 4em;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 1em;
 border-bottom: .1em solid #dddddd;
  }
h2 {
 font-size: 2.1em;
  }
p {
 font-size: 10em;
 color: white;
 padding-top: 1em;
  }

@media only screen and (min-width: 319px) {

 .menu {
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 3.3em;
    color: black;
  }

  .menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    border-top: #dddddd 1px solid;
  }   

  .menu li {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
    border-bottom: #dddddd 1px solid;
  }

  .menu li:hover {
    display: block;
    background: #585858;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
      cursor: crosshair;
  }

  .menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    color: black;
  }

  .menu ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }

  .menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
  }

  #nav-icon4 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 25px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -47px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: cell;
  }

  #nav-icon4 span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background: darkred;
    border-radius: 7px;
    opacity: 2;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  }

  #nav-icon4 span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }

  #nav-icon4 span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }

  #nav-icon4 span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 20px;
     -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }

  #nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 0;
    left: 6px;
  }

  #nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(2) {
    width: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  #nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 25px;
    left: 6px;
  }   
  }


@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {   
     h2 {
      z-index: 1000000;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      }

        p {
            font-size: 20em;
            color: white;
            padding-top: 1em;
  }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
  }

  li {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: .9em;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }
.menu ul {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    }
.menu li {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    }
 .menu li:hover {
    cursor: crosshair;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: .4em;
    padding-right: 0em;
    padding-left: 0em;
   }

.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

#nav-icon4 {
    display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 922px) {
    li {
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 18px;

    }
.menu {
    padding-right: 1px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (min-width : 1400px) {
    header {
       height: 5em;
      line-height: 5em;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 2.6em;    
    }
    li {
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    }
    .menu {
        padding-right: 1px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
}

    </style>

 <title>hamburgers</title>
 </head>

 <body>
     <header>

      <span>Shine Design</span>
      <div id="nav-icon4">
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
      </div>

     </header>

     <div class="menu">
      <ul>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK ONE</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK TWO</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK THREE</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK FOUR</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK FIVE</li>
       </a>
      </ul>
     </div>

   </body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#nav-icon4').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
      });
    });
    </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: Why are you using an old version of jQuery?

Comment: I don't know! I didn't know I was using an old version. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know I was just commenting on it because it's old as indicated by the version string in the CDN URL. If this is a newish project you shouldn't be using jQuery 1 considering there's already a V3.

Comment: I will look into that and change it! Thanks for that tip! It is a new project and I am new to jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function `slideToggle()` toggles the display property and it add it into the element style of the menu which makes it more priority than using class

so to resolve the issue add **important** to `display:block;` in the media screen `min-width : 768px;`

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
   .....
   .menu {
    display: block!important;
     .....
   }
}
```

[**See updated codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvEZWM)

Comment: This was the simplest and best explained answer and it works perfectly. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Put a `display : block !important;` in the .menu, the function slideToggle() will put a style `display:none` inline in the element .menu, so when you come back to the high resolution, .menu still display: none

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery and js at the end or before  tag

```
 <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");</script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

use this

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html lang="en">

 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: #ffffff;
 background-color: black;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }

header {
 width: 100%;
 background: #ffffff;
 position: fixed;
 height: 4em;
 line-height: 4em;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 1em;
 border-bottom: .1em solid #dddddd;
  }
h2 {
 font-size: 2.1em;
  }
p {
 font-size: 10em;
 color: white;
 padding-top: 1em;
  }

@media only screen and (min-width: 319px) {

 .menu {
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 3.3em;
    color: black;
  }

  .menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    border-top: #dddddd 1px solid;
  }   

  .menu li {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
    border-bottom: #dddddd 1px solid;
  }

  .menu li:hover {
    display: block;
    background: #585858;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
      cursor: crosshair;
  }

  .menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    color: black;
  }

  .menu ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }

  .menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
  }

  #nav-icon4 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 25px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -47px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: cell;
  }

  #nav-icon4 span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background: darkred;
    border-radius: 7px;
    opacity: 2;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  }

  #nav-icon4 span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }

  #nav-icon4 span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }

  #nav-icon4 span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 20px;
     -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }

  #nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 0;
    left: 6px;
  }

  #nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(2) {
    width: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  #nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 25px;
    left: 6px;
  }   
  }


@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {   
     h2 {
      z-index: 1000000;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      }

        p {
            font-size: 20em;
            color: white;
            padding-top: 1em;
  }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
  }

  li {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: .9em;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }
.menu ul {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    }
.menu li {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    }
 .menu li:hover {
    cursor: crosshair;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: .4em;
    padding-right: 0em;
    padding-left: 0em;
   }

.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

#nav-icon4 {
    display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 922px) {
    li {
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 18px;

    }
.menu {
    padding-right: 1px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (min-width : 1400px) {
    header {
       height: 5em;
      line-height: 5em;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 2.6em;    
    }
    li {
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    }
    .menu {
        padding-right: 1px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
}

    </style>

 <title>hamburgers</title>
 </head>

 <body>
     <header>

      <span>Shine Design</span>
      <div id="nav-icon4">
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
      </div>

     </header>

     <div class="menu">
      <ul>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK ONE</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK TWO</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK THREE</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK FOUR</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK FIVE</li>
       </a>
      </ul>
     </div>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");</script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
   </body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#nav-icon4').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
      });
    });
    </script>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a short example of  things need to be done. Added some jquery codes to make it work the way you want .

> **Step 1** - Add class `hide-nav` on **window width**

```
      /* logic For window width */
  if ($(window).width() > 768) {
  //  $('.menu').addClass('hide-nav');
    $('.menu').addClass('show-nav');
  } else {
    $('.menu').removeClass('hide-nav');
  }
```

> **Step 2 -** Add class `hide-nav` on **window resize**

```
      function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      $('.menu').addClass('hide-nav');
      $('.menu').removeClass('show-nav');
    }
  else {

    $('.menu').addClass('show-nav');
}
  }

  $(window).resize(resize)
    .trigger('resize');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav-icon4').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $(".menu").slideToggle("slow");
  });

  /* logic For window width */
  if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    //  $('.menu').addClass('hide-nav');
    $('.menu').addClass('show-nav');
  } else {
    $('.menu').removeClass('hide-nav');
  }
});

function resize() {
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $('.menu').addClass('hide-nav');
    $('.menu').removeClass('show-nav');
  } else {

    $('.menu').addClass('show-nav');
  }
}

$(window).resize(resize)
  .trigger('resize');
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ffffff;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  height: 4em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 1em;
  border-bottom: .1em solid #dddddd;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.1em;
}

p {
  font-size: 10em;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 319px) {
  .menu {
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 3.3em;
    color: black;
  }
  .menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    border-top: #dddddd 1px solid;
  }
  .menu li {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
    border-bottom: #dddddd 1px solid;
  }
  .menu li:hover {
    display: block;
    background: #585858;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
    cursor: crosshair;
  }
  .menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    color: black;
  }
  .menu ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
  .menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
  }
  #nav-icon4 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 25px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -60px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: cell;
  }
  #nav-icon4 span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background: darkred;
    border-radius: 7px;
    opacity: 2;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  }
  #nav-icon4 span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }
  #nav-icon4 span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }
  #nav-icon4 span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 20px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }
  #nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 0;
    left: 6px;
  }
  #nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(2) {
    width: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  #nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 25px;
    left: 6px;
  }
}


/* Break at Devices such as Tablets, Desktops */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  h2 {
    z-index: 1000000;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 20em;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 1em;
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  li {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
  li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: .9em;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  .menu ul {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
  }
  .menu li {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
  }
  .menu li:hover {
    cursor: crosshair;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: .4em;
    padding-right: 0em;
    padding-left: 0em;
  }
  .menu ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  #nav-icon4 {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* Medium Devices, Desktops */

@media only screen and (min-width: 922px) {
  li {
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 18px;
  }
  .menu {
    padding-right: 1px;
  }
}


/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
  header {
    height: 5em;
    line-height: 5em;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 2.6em;
  }
  li {
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
  .menu {
    padding-right: 1px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}

.show-nav {
  display: block !important;
}

.hide-nav {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="hamburgers.css">

  <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
  </script>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="ham.js"></script>

  <title>hamburgers</title>

</head>

<body>


  <header>
    <h2><span>Shine Design</span></h2>
    <div id="nav-icon4">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="menu" id="menuExpand">
    <ul>
      <a href="#">
        <li>LINK ONE</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>LINK TWO</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>LINK THREE</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>LINK FOUR</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>LINK FIVE</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <main>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```